# Highchart - Drilldown after chaging the type, approch differes.. is it correct way?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

i am making a chart, using the highchart, it works fine. in the highchart i need to implement a drilldown approach. i did, it works fine, in case if i am not change the drilldown type, in case if i change the drilldown type to different, the approch of the drilldown charts varies. i am not an expert in this... i beleave something going on wrong with my code, any one can advice me the right way to change the drilldown type approach?

this is my current code :

```
var chart;
$(document).ready(function(){
    var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
        categories = ['MSIE'],
        name = "Browser Brand",
        data = [
                {
                    y:55.11,
                    color:colors[0],
                    drilldown:{
                        name:'MSIE versions',
                        categories : ['MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                        data:[33.06,71.02],
                        color: colors[1]
                    }
                }
                ]
    function setChart(name,categories,data,color){
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
        chart.series[0].remove();
        chart.addSeries({
            name:name,
            data:data,
            color:color || 'green',
            type:'pie'//if i applied the type i can't come back from child to parent, as well title not visible. if i removed this then title shows, i can come back to parent.
        })
    }

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart:{
            renderTo:'drill',
            type:'column'
            },
        title:{
            text:"Browser marketshare"
        },
        subtitle:{
            text:'Click to see the version'
        },
        xAxis:{
            categories:categories
        },
        plotOptions:{
            column:{
                cursor:'pointer',
                point:{
                    events:{
                        click:function(){
                            var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                            if(drilldown){
                                setChart(drilldown.name,drilldown.categories,drilldown.data,drilldown.color);
                            }else{
                                setChart(name, categories, data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series:[
            {
                name:name,
                data:data,
                color:colors[1]
            }
        ]
    })
})
```

Any one can help me?

Comment: have you solved this?  i want to drill down from column to range